# footer goes over other html elements

Tags: php, html, css

I have a footer section which i will include to every page of my website.So i took the help of php and include it with

```
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

But my problem is it gets stuck in a fixed position. If i add html elements before the footer section it goes on top the other elements.How it can be solved?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
  #mydiv{
     width:350px;
     height:550px;

     background:#d3a625;
     position:fixed;
     top:70px;
     left:300px;
     position:relative;

  }

  #mydiv input{

       position:absolute;
       right:0px;
       margin-left:15px;
  }
  #image{
     width:60px;
     height:60px;
     border:1px solid black;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>' id='mydiv' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
   </br>
   <label for='username'>username</label>
   <input type='text' name='username' value='' autocomplete='off'>
   </br>
   <label for='password'>password</label>
   <input type='password' name='password' value='' autocomplete='off'>
   </br>

   <label for='password_again'>password_again</label>
   <input type='password' name='password_again' value='' autocomplete='off'>
   </br>

   <label for='name'>Full Name</label>
   <input type='text' name='name' value='' autocomplete='off'>
   </br>
   </br>
   <input type='submit' value='register' >
   <input type='hidden' name='token' value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">


</form>
<script>

    function readfile(e){

         if(window.File && window.FileReader &&  window.FileList){

                var file=e.target.files[0];
                console.log(file.size);

                var fileReader=new FileReader();

                fileReader.onload=(function(file){
                    return function(e){

                         var div=document.getElementById('image');
                         var image=document.createElement('img');
                         image.setAttribute('src',e.target.result);
                         image.setAttribute('style','width:60px;height:60px;');
                         div.appendChild(image);


                }})(file);
         fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
         }else{
             alert('file api not compatible with your browser');
         }  


    }
    document.getElementById('up').addEventListener('change',readfile,false);
</script>
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

footer.php:

```
<div id='footer'>
   <div id='col1' class='fdiv'>
       <ul>
          <li><a href='#'>faq</a></li>
          <li><a href='#'>faq</a></li>
          <li><a href='#'>faq</a></li>
          <li><a href='#'>faq</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div >
       <div id='col2' class='fdiv'>
       <ul>
          <li><a href='#'>faq</a></li>
          <li><a href='#'>faq</a></li>
          <li><a href='#'>faq</a></li>
          <li><a href='#'>faq</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div >
       <div id='col3' class='fdiv'>
       <ul>
          <li><a href='#'>faq</a></li>
          <li><a href='#'>faq</a></li>
          <li><a href='#'>faq</a></li>
          <li><a href='#'>faq</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
       <div id='col4' class='fdiv'>
       <ul>
          <li><a href='#'>faq</a></li>
          <li><a href='#'>faq</a></li>
          <li><a href='#'>faq</a></li>
          <li><a href='#'>faq</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div >
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
   *{
     margin:0px;
     padding:0px;
   }
   body{
      height:1500px;
   }

     #footer{
         width:100%;
         height:170px;
         position:absolute;
         background:crimson;
         bottom:10px;
      }
      .fdiv{

         width:24%;
         height:100%;
         position:relative;
         float:left;

         text-align:center;

      }
      #footer a{
        text-decoration:none;
        color:white;
        font-size:17px;
      }
      #footer li{
        list-style-type:none;
      }
      #loginform{
          width:250px;
          height:100px;
          border:1px dashed black;
          background:olive;
          position:relative;
          top:100px;
          left:40%;
          text-align:center;
      }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add the HTML/CSS you have in footer.php please, makes it difficult to help without seeing that.

Answer (score 0):

why absolute positining such easy markup? 
+ we really cant see your generated output so its hard tell where exactly error is.
It can be many places.
When making layout is alyways good using some wrappers or containers. Than you can manage make some space with padding or margin for footer.

Example with table tried to help coz it can help when you havent ended your elements correctly.

Show us generated output and we can tell more.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><?php include('footer.php'); ?></td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

Comment: why i need to use a table?

Comment: Well, I think is not going to be over the other element. Try to change position atribute of your div to.

Comment: I recomed you to use tables for your site. You can put a Div inside a <td>. It will keep your site more organized

Comment: Asking someone to put a footer into a table row like this to solve a CSS issue is just plain bad advice...

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer to this question! Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, because it can be difficult for the original poster (or future readers) to understand the logic behind them. Please, edit your question and include an explanation of your code so that others can benefit from your answer. Thanks!